# How to access UIAlertView action over Application in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uialertview

Hello I am using here UIWebView and load request for map . Now I have all done successfully but when I run app first time then Pop up show, I am attaching image here [image]

Now I want to ask how to access this pop up actions (Don't allow and oK) ,because this is by default generated first time when we app run. I don't know how to access "Ok" button I want to write some code on "Ok" button.

So please anyone tell me how to access these pop up buttons in my case.

Comment: This is generated in attempt of asking for access permission from user. I don't think you can edit it.

Comment: @rahul its default so no need to make change in that. you can click on ok button.

Comment: Ya, I know it's default but I want to access this ,I try to access using CLlocation delegate but no success .

Comment: Try to sneak into UIWebViewDelegate functions, check the urls it is changing after your press OK, it may work. else use GoogleMap SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol to get call back event for that alert button pressed by authorization status.

`locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`

Tells the delegate that the authorization status for the application changed.

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status`

There are various authorization status provided mention as follows :

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,

   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,

   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,

   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,

} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

`kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`
The user has not yet made a choice regarding whether this app can use location services.

`kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`
This app is not authorized to use location services. The user cannot change this app’s status, possibly due to active restrictions such as parental controls being in place.

`kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`
The user explicitly denied the use of location services for this app or location services are currently disabled in Settings.

`kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`
This app is authorized to use location services.

Comment: This will do your work if you want write some code on "Ok" button action ,write it in loop after getting kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized status

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the message that is shown on `UIAlertView`, but you can not access the control of <kbd>ok</kbd> button, because iOS don't provide a delegate to access this button.

The alert is only shown for the first time, you launch the app and not after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only control the condition to present this alert but you cannot control the ok button